# How to add the active facet items to the url before submitting a form?

Tags: drupal-7

I have enabled two contributed modules, views and facetapi. With these modules I have created a Search view with an exposed filter 'Search Full Text' and a facet block for filtering.

From this page I had select some items in the facet block(this will result in filtering the page with the selected items).This is working just fine and after that I enter some value in the exposed filter(Search Full Text) and hit the search button provided by the views. Then the problem arise it will only filter based on the exposed filter and ignores the items that I had previously selected in the facet block.

So what my requirement is that I want to keep the selected facet items with the exposed filter (i.e exposed filter + facet filter) when I click on the search button provided by the views.

So to achieve this requirement what came to my mind is to look into the `$_GET` parameters    So I had take a look at the `$_GET` parameters in the `hook_views_pre_build(&$view)`. Then I realize that the URL is formed before the submitting the form.

So how the URL is been constructed when I hit the search button in the view and appending all the exposed filter to the URL?

Is it possible to append the active items of the facet items to the URL before submitting a form.

Is there any better way to do this than looking into to the `$_GET` parameters.

Comment: try $_REQUEST to get form values.